# If someone deMOSSes my AGPL v3 licensed code can they make it closed source and release it as a product?

Tags: agpl

I have an API which is licensed under AGPL v3. Let's suppose someone modifies the API code to make it look completely different from the original code and also deletes any history. Then he goes on to release the modified code as a product and makes it closed-source. Will he face any legal implications?

P.S: I know this is highly unethical. I just want to know if someone can do it and get away legally.

Comment: there is an open source forum you can ask this on. but I think the practical case is that as you give away the software for free, you have suffered no damages

Comment: Ewan says who? And in the USA you can always ask for $150,000 in statutory damages.

Answer (score 0):

“Someone modified it” - so they create a derived work. Which they can only legally distribute with the permission of the copyright holder, for example by publishing under the AGPL license. So we have a copyright infringement and you can sue them. Modifying and removing license text to hide that it is a derived work makes it worse.

Comment: Whether an API is even subject to intellectual property *at all* is still a very much open topic, and I believe most software practitioners believe it shouldn't be. Oracle v. Google is still ongoing after 8 years, so the question is clearly not as clear-cut as you make it out to be. In particular, one side argues that APIs cannot be protected at all, whereas the other side argues that even if you do *not* use a single line of code at all, it is still a derived work.